# flask url confusion - getting 404 or 500 dependng on url

Tags: javascript, python, flask

I am new to web programming.
Writing a simple ajax call to run a python function via 2 files
javascriptPython3.html  & javascriptPython3.py

Client is a macbook & firefox 80.0.1
Webserver is a raspberry pi Apache/2.4.25 (Raspbian) Server at rbp Port 80

On the server I run:

```
export FLASK_DEBUG=1
export FLASK_APP=javascriptPython3.py
flask run -h 192.168.1.6
 * Serving Flask app "javascriptPython3"
 * Forcing debug mode on
 * Running on http://192.168.1.6:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
 * Restarting with stat
 * Debugger is active!
 * Debugger pin code: 318-477-733
192.168.1.3 - - [10/Dec/2022 14:44:55] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
192.168.1.3 - - [10/Dec/2022 14:44:57] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
192.168.1.3 - - [10/Dec/2022 14:44:58] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```

On the client macbook browser:
http://192.168.1.6:5000/
Each Time I reload the webpage, I get an output line in the flask run.

So far so good.

But when I browse to javascriptPython3.html on the client, and click the button, I get 404 not found in the browser console.

If I change the ajax url to "javascriptPython3.py" I get 500 Internal Server error.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
#from flask import Flask, request, render_template
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/', methods=['GET','POST'])
def makeupper():
#      javascriptdata=request
#      javascriptdata=javascriptdata.upper()
      outputfile = open("javascriptPython.out", "a")
      outputfile.write("Hello from Python\n\n")

      return "ABCCC"
```

javascriptPython3.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
     <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script>
     function successFun(pythonResponse) {
            window.alert(pythonResponse);
           document.getElementById('output1').value = pythonResponse;
        }
         function runPython() {
            window.alert("We just called runPython()");
            $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/javascriptPython3.py",
//            url: "/",
//            data: "abc",
            success: successFun()
             });
         }
      </script>

 </head>
 <body>
   <p> run python from javascrpt </p>
   <br>
   <input type="button" onClick="runPython()"  value="Run Python" />
   <br>
   <br>
   <p> Output text </p>
   <textarea id="output1" rows="4" cols="50"> </textarea>
        
</body>
</html>
```

I was expecting to see javascriptPython.out get appended everytime
I clicked the button.

It got appended when I kept reloading http://192.168.1.6:5000/ just as I wanted it to

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. In your own words, where the code says `@app.route('/', methods=['GET','POST'])`, what exactly do you think this means? In particular, what do you think the `'/'` part is indicating? What URLs do you expect will become valid, as a result of this part of the code existing? Did you try to read the documentation for Flask, in order to understand what it means by a "route", and what they are for? Did you try to follow a tutorial for Flask?

Comment: Hello David, I have looked at several tutorials, but not rea official docs yet.

Comment: Hello David, Sorry ; My last comment was no complete. I have looked at several tutorials, but not read official docs yet. I used router('/') just to get to the documentroot on web server.  What I want to do is route  to the python function makeupper and run it. I am looking into using url: "{{ url_for('makeupper') }}" in my ajax call

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got it working ; Again I was trying to simply route to (run) a python function via ajax call.

I just needed to use a complete URL with IP and port, pointing to the apache server in my html file

```
AJAX URL:   url: "http://192.168.1.9:5000/foo",
python route:     @app.route('/foo', methods=['GET','POST'])
```

Answer (score 1):

> But when I browse to javascriptPython3.html on the client

That is correct. In your code, there is no route for `javascriptPython3.html`

**A very high level/simplistic explanation**

1. Flask returns (serves up) content based on paths (routes) you have defined in your python code. It can return content as plain text or it can return the content via a template (html page) i.e. `render_template(<html_page>)`
2. In your code, you have only defined one route - `@app.route('/'` which corresponds to http://192.168.1.6:5000/ . Think of it this way - anything you have defined in as a route comes after your server address which is http://192.168.1.6:5000
3. If you want to navigate to `javascriptPython3.html` i.e. you want to be able to type the url http://192.168.1.6:5000/javascriptPython3.html, then you have to define a route for it in your code i.e. you need something like `app.route('/javascriptPython3.html')`
4. Since it looks like you want to display `javascriptPython3.html` when you open your server (i.e when you go to your root i.e. `/`), you should modify your existing code to

```
    from flask import Flask, request, render_template
    app = Flask(__name__)

    @app.route('/', methods=['GET','POST'])
    def makeupper():
      outputfile = open("javascriptPython.out", "a")
      outputfile.write("Hello from Python\n\n")

      return render_template('javascriptPython3.html')
```

Comment: Hello and thank you for the detailed explanation.   I am not trying to display anything right now, and I am not trying to transfer data back and forth until later. Just want to click a button and have a python function run on the server. I am looking into using url: "{{ url_for('makeupper') }}" in my ajax call.  I finally found a video that uses url_for ; How to POST request in a Python Website using AJAX ? [Flask & Django]  by JimShapedCoding Jan 26 2022

Comment: Read my explanation again. Flask works by you entering a url and the code defined for the path in your url will run. You have entered a url with a path of 'javascriptPython3.html' but you don't have any code defined for that path. This is why you get a 404 which means 'not found'

Comment: Hi,  Just read your explanation again  and changed the code:   The .py file route is now @app.route('/javascriptPython3.py', methods=['GET','POST'])   AND    in the .html   url:"/javascriptPython3.py",    Next, I run  flask run -h 192.168.1.6  AND  browser test of http://192.168.1.6:5000/javascriptPython3.py   works ; COOL all good so far ......  BUT when I browse to http://rbp/javascriptPython3.html and click button, I get 500 error, in js console, which is my original issue.

Comment: This is the highlights of the stack trace, but the whole thing is probably too long to paste in here:   send
http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js:4:25549
ajax
http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js:4:21302
runPython
http://rbp/javascriptPython3.html:12:15
onclick
http://rbp/javascriptPython3.html:1:1

Comment: You keep on typing ```javascriptPython3.html``` in the browser but you still don't have anything in your python code that says ```app.route('/javascriptPython3.html')```. What you did was to add ```@app.route('/javascriptPython3.py',``` but '/javascriptPython3.py', isn't javascriptPython3.html. Apart from this, my response said not to even do any of this but to simply do ```return render_templae('javascriptPython3.html')``` and then just load your default server i.e. 192.168.1.6:5000/

Comment: OK, I changed the code in .py to @app.route('/javascriptPython3.html', methods=['GET','POST'])  And changed the return line to: return render_template('javascriptPython3.html') Still got 500 err, and these 2 lines do not run:   outputfile = open("javascriptPython.out", "a")
      outputfile.write("Hello from Python\n\n")  I can run a standalone python program via ajax call, but wanted to run a python  <u>function</u>  instead using app.route. I have a bigger python program I eventually want to run.  Thanks again for your help and patience on this.

Comment: What you have done isn't what I said or posted. Please, go back to my first response to you and implement the code exactly as I have it. Then run your flask, you should get the contents of javascriptPython3.html displayed on your screen. After you successfully do that, then we can work on your next target which is - you want something to happen when you click a button.

Comment: OK, I made my .py file like you have in your first post. The last line,  'render...',   did not have a return in front of it but it did not make a difference either way.  When I click the button I don't get any errors in the js console ; I looked in the Response preview section of he console, and I see my webpage, so seems this is what we were looking for.

Comment: I missed 'return'. I have modified my code now and that last part should read ```return render_template('javascriptPython3.html')```. Update your code and run it again. You should have your web page displayed in the browser. Let me know when that is done and we can deal with the next step

Comment: OK, changed the last line ; added return before render....  Kind of have a shade of doubt, because javascriptPython.out did not get created, but no errors and I saw my page in the js console response preview so guess it's ok.

Comment: I did a quick test running flask run -h 192.168.1.6
 * Serving Flask app "javascriptPython3"
 * Forcing debug mode on
 * Running on http://192.168.1.6:5000/        AND   then  browsing to http://192.168.1.6:5000/ ; Got jinja2.exceptions.TemplateNotFound: javascriptPython3.html ;

Comment: 1) You should have a folder in your project called ```templates```. The name should be exactly as I have written it (don't change the case of any letter or call it anything else). 2) Your ```javascriptPython3.html``` should go into that folder. After this, you should find a tutorial on Flask. It seems you're missing the very fundamentals of Flask

Answer (score 0):

Below are the 2 files that work

```
export FLASK_APP=javascriptPython3.py 
export FLASK_DEBUG=1  
flask run -h 192.168.1.9
```

```
Browse to:  http://192.168.1.9/javascriptPython3.html
```

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
from flask import Flask, request, render_template

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/foo', methods=['GET','POST'])
def foo():
#      javascriptdata=request
#      javascriptdata=javascriptdata.upper()
      outputfile = open("javascriptPython.out", "a")
      outputfile.write("Hello from Python\n\n")

      return "ABCCC"
```

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
     <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.
min.js"></script>
      <script>
     function successFun(pythonResponse) {
            window.alert(pythonResponse);
           document.getElementById('output1').value = pythonResponse;
        }
         function runPython() {
            window.alert("We just called runPython()");
            $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "http://192.168.1.9:5000/foo",
//            data: "abc",
            success: successFun()
             })
         }
      </script>

 </head>
 <body>
   <p> run python from javascrpt </p>
   <br>
   <input type="button" onClick="runPython()"  value="Run Python" />
   <br>
   <br>
   <p> Output text </p>
   <textarea id="output1" rows="4" cols="50"> </textarea>
        
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).